# Hide div after scrolling it out of viewport, but maintain scroll position

Tags: jquery

I have a full screen box (#doorMat) that pops in to view on page load. The box has both a link to click to close it (works great), as well I'm trying to make a function to remove it if the user scrolls down the page past it. I'd like the doorMat div to be removed/detached but not have the screen adjust with it.

Here is my current code:

```
var height = $(window).height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if ( scroll > height ) {
    hideDoorMat();
}
});

function hideDoorMat() {
if($('#doorMat').length){
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
$('#doorMat').remove();
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
});
}
}
```

It works, sort of, except when I scroll past the doorMat, the content still shifts up, as well as there being a delay on the scroll back to content. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you:
http://jsfiddle.net/s6dozk4y/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if ( scroll > height ) {
        hideDoorMat(true);
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
```

and:

```
function hideDoorMat(withoutAnimation) {
    if($('#doorMat').length){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#doorMat').remove();
    if(!withoutAnimation){
     $('body').animate({
           scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
        });
    }
    Cookies.set( 'b2wcookie', 'doormat', { expires: 1, path: '/' } );
    }
}
```

I have disabled animation and adjusted window scroll position on element removal.

Comment: Smooth man, I had to move the `if($('#doorMat').length){` to the scroll action as it kept repeating the scroll to top over and over, but after that it works flawless. Thanks!